# How to set xlim for a plot in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

why doesn't "xlim" work in the following script:

```
from pylab import *
from numpy import *

x = linspace (0, 2*pi, 100)
y = sin (x)
clf ()
plot (x, y, 'b-', label = "sin (x)")
xlim (0, 2*pi)
axis ('equal')
grid ()
legend ()
show ()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you leave out the use of `axis('equal')` aspect ratio, the limitation of the x-values works for me. Possibly this is different for different Matplotlib backends. I am using Mac Os X default backend.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Explained a bit more. However, I cannot give a precise justification why this is so.